# scrreprt .cls is missing

Tags: koma-script, mactex

I get the following error on TeXShop when trying to compile:

```
./thesis.tex:2: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

! LaTeX Error: File `scrreprt .cls' not found.
```

My .tex file looks the following:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt }
\title{Abstract}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

I updated all packages with TeX Live Utility.
And when I select the koma-script package in the program, the scrreprt is available.

But still get that error!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to delete the space at the end of `scrreprt`, before the closing brace.

You can tell because the system is complaining about not seeing `"scrreprt .cls"` (note the space).